# How to break a for-each loop in C# when archiving a parent and its children?

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

I am currently receiving a "System.InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'" error when running this code. How can I break the loop so it archives properly?

Comment: Why are you trying to serialize a RuntineModule?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem correctly then the following should suffice:

```
return ArchiveCurrentObject(child);
```

Hope it helps and sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: When I tried adding this to my code, it gave me the error that "The name 'child' does not exist in the current context. For clarification, I need the return statement to end the loop when there are no more children left to archive.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean to stop the loop?

then you could use a break or a return:

```
foreach (string A in StringCollection)
{ 
    if (A == "Something") { break; } 
}
```

Comment: The break fixed the error, thank you. However, the .delete functionality I wrote isn't archiving the object. Do you know how I would write a reroute function to NotInWorkflow?

Comment: I think you could have a look then at Fortega's answer, he creates a list of already archived objects and stopping the function from getting called if it sees that the object as already been archived

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a circular reference in your data, meaning that one of the objects is a descendant of itself. You could keep a list of all already archived objects and break the recursion if one of the objects is met again.

```
private void ArchiveCurrentObject(ObjectInfo currentObject)
{
    ArchiveCurrentObject(currentObject, new List<ObjectInfo>());
}

private void ArchiveCurrentObject(ObjectInfo currentObject, List<ObjectInfo> alreadyArchived)
{
   //check if you already archived this object
   if(alreadyArchived.Any(a => a == currentObject) return;

   //delete if the object has the right workflow state
   if (currentObject.WorkflowState == WorkflowStateType.InWorkFlow)
   {
       DataProviderCreationHelper.RetreieveWorkitemDataProvider()
       .Delete(new List<int>{currentObject.WorkflowId});
    }

    //add object to 'already archived' list
    alreadyArchived.Add(currentObject);

    //archive the children
    foreach (ObjectInfo child in currentObject.Children)
    {    
        ArchiveCurrentObject(child);
    }

}
```